# load a page that has twitter post embeded

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently doing this:

```
$(function(){ 
  $('mydiv').load('page2.com');
}
```

I have two pages, page1 and page2. page2 has Twitter post embedded in it. Although page2 got loaded it does not include the Twitter embedded post.

How do I load page2 to include the Twitter post?

Comment: You need to run whatever JS logic which decorates the twitter post embedded in to that HTML *after* your AJAX call completes.

Comment: please sir shed more light

Comment: Well, you must be executing some JS logic in page2 for the Twitter post to be pulled in. That doesn't happen magically. You need to call that same logic in page1 after you make the `load()` request to pull in the content of page2.

Comment: i got it! Thanks